Give python program location services access via command line on MacOS
I am trying to run a python program requiring location services on MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1. I was using iTerm2 and expected a pop-up asking if the app could have access to my location. However, nothing showed up, so I went to System Settings > Privacy & Security > Location Services and found a new app available: Python. I toggled it on but found the program still doesn't have access to my location, and every time I restart system settings Python is toggled off again. This behaviour seems to reproduce only with Python and not with e.g. Calendar or Tuta Mail.

Having used Linux in the past, I thought an error-proof way to get to the bottom of this was to try replicating the process in the command line and look for errors. Nevertheless, I was only able to find a way to turn on or off location services completely, and not specific apps.
Since I have no more ideas on how to proceed, thought I would ask for help, let me know if more information is needed, and thanks in advance.

Check if you have other python version installed with Brew:
brew list | grep -i python

Remove them with this command:
brew remove <package name>

After that default python from Apple will be used and it will show pop-up dialog asking for permissions.

Thank you! This seemed to do the trick, though I don't understand why it doesn't work the same with python installed from Brew. Sorry for the late response.
